# Inconsistent Image dimensions in FaceDetector detect method

Tags: android, android-camera2, google-vision

I am trying to detect and crop the image of a face using the 
com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector class,

The facedetector object is created as,

```
 detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .build();


 detector.setProcessor(
            new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
                    .build());
```

The camera source is created with Camera2 Api as,

```
mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f)
                .build();
```

Then on a button click the takePicture method in CameraSource is called to process the Image as,

```
mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback(){

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,
                        bytes.length, options);
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(temp).build();
                SparseArray<Face> faces =detector.detect(frame);
                System.out.println("faces: "+faces.size());

            }
        });
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
inconsistent image dimensions

Native face detection failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error detecting faces.

com.google.android.gms.vision.face.NativeFaceDetectorImpl.detectFacesJni(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector.detect(Unknown Source:41)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work, to detect faces from files,

The solution is to create the detector object with setting, 
trackingEnabled ->false,  and if you want to track multiple faces, setProminentFaceOnly->false.

With tracking enabled, the detector works well with an associated camera preview to track the face with id. Will post a detailed explanation of the reason behind this solution, as of create the detector object as,

```
detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(false) // <-- set to false
            .setTrackingEnabled(false) // <-- set to false
            .build();
```